# Zeromq multiple subscribers

Tags: python, zeromq

I am trying to send a video stream from one program to an arbitrary number of clients (like 0-10 clients)

I can easily do this with one publisher and one subscriber, but if i start another client app it will not start recieving any data until i close the first one.

My code looks like this:
***SERVER***

```py
import zmq
import imageio
import simplejpeg


context = zmq.Context()
publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
publisher.connect("ipc:///tmp/v4l")



gif = imageio.get_reader('video.mp4')

while True:
    for frame in gif:
        frame = simplejpeg.encode_jpeg(frame)
        publisher.send(frame)
```

***Client***

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.bind("ipc:///tmp/v4l")
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')
i = 0
while True:
    data = subscriber.recv()
    print(i)
    i = i+1
```

in the documentation (https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html) it states

> Scenario #2 is more known, general pattern where multiple subscribers
> subscribes to messages/topics being published by a publisher.
> though i cannot figure out why this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the publisher bind() and the multiple subscribers connect().  You can only bind/listen to the same endpoint once but you can connect many times.